# MongoDB Error 2nd time calling function: TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm using the following function to add an array of documents to a MongoDB collection.

```
function recipesToDB(recipes) {
   mongo.connect(uristring, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
         console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
      } else {
         console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);

         db.createCollection('recipes', function(err, collection) {});

         var collection = db.collection('recipes');

         collection.insert(recipes, {continueOnError: true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
               console.log('ERROR:' + err);
            } else {
               console.log('success');
            }
         });
      }
   });
}
```

The above function works to add my recipes array to the MongoDB recipes collection. But, when I call the function twice(30 seconds apart), it fails the second time with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because connecting a second time isn't working. Instead, connect once in a more global location and then access the global connection from this function.

```
var mongoDb;
function connectToDb(done){
  mongo.connect(uristring, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
         console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
      } else {
         console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
         mongoDb = db;
         done();
      }
  }
}

connectToDb(function(){
   recipesToDB(yourRecipesObject);
});


function recipesToDB(recipes) {


         mongoDb.createCollection('recipes', function(err, collection) {});

         var collection = mongoDb.collection('recipes');

         collection.insert(recipes, {continueOnError: true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
               console.log('ERROR:' + err);
            } else {
               console.log('success');
            }
         });
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Why can I not tag anyone every on this site!!

Answer (score 1):

If mongodb has mongod.lock,this error should come,
This is the way to remove mongod.lock: **sudo rm mongod.lock**,after you must restart the mongodb,that is **sudo service mongod restart**